Two definitions of antisymmetrization of a tensor?
I am currently learning about tensors and the exterior product, and I have found some contradictory information. I have seen some sources define the antisymmetrization of a tensor as the following:

Let $T \in V^{\otimes k}$ and $\sigma \in S_k$ be a permutation. The antisymmetrization of $T$ is defined as
$$\mathscr{A}(T) := \frac{1}{k!} \sum_{\sigma \in S_k} \text{sgn}(\sigma) \sigma(T)$$

This is defined such that $\mathscr{A}(\mathscr{A}(T)) = \mathscr{A}(T)$.
However, I have seen many texts define this operation in the same way but omitting the factor of $1/k!$. Let's call this version of the operation $\mathscr{A}'$. This definition leads to the identity $\mathscr{A}'(\mathscr{A}'(T)) = k! \mathscr{A}'(T)$
This has led to a lot of confusion regarding my understanding of the exterior product as the exterior product is defined as the following operation:

Let $\omega^1 \in \textstyle \bigwedge^k (V)$ and $\omega^2 \in \textstyle \bigwedge^\ell (V)$. The exterior product of $\omega^1$ and $\omega^2$ is defined as
$$\omega^1 \wedge \omega^2 := \frac{1}{k!\ell!}\mathscr{A}(\omega^1 \otimes \omega^2)$$

Can someone please clear up this confusion?

Welcome to MSE. I encourage you to take a look at this post. I think the explanation is quite clear, but should you have further questions, don’t hesitate to leave a comment.

@KurtG. The linked question and answer make no mention of the definition of the exterior product or its relationship to the definition of the alternator, which is the heart of this question. The answers here are far more interesting in addressing that. Why exactly does the OP need to edit this one?

@blargoner I have retracted the close vote for various reasons. Most importantly: there seems a new autogenerated comment that comes with it. The previous one: "Does this answer your question?" I liked much better.

Your convention for the factor in front of the antisymmetrization determines a corresponding convention for the factor in front of the exterior product. The factor is uniquely determined by the requirement that it makes the exterior product associative, so in some sense it doesn't matter, but different conventions will make different equations appear more or less nice.
I believe but have not checked carefully that if you use $A$ then the factor should be ${k+\ell \choose k}$ and if you use $A'$ then the factor should be $\frac{1}{k! \ell!}$ (so what you wrote is not quite right, and you can see that it doesn't do the right thing when $k = 0$).
This can all be avoided by choosing an alternate definition of the exterior power based on quotienting the tensor product rather than considering the subspace of antisymmetric tensors. With this definition the wedge product is just directly inherited from the tensor product and there's no need to antisymmetrize or consider any factors anywhere, and it inherits associativity from associativity of the tensor product.
If I had to pick between $A$ and $A'$ then I would go with $A$. An operation called "antisymmetrization" should not do anything to a tensor that is already antisymmetric, so it makes sense to require $A(A(T)) = A(T)$ (idempotence).

Algebraists, of course, prefer the quotient definition. Differential geometers, however, tend to prefer the definition that gives a subalgebra of the tensor algebra; for starters, it's awkward want to work with differential forms (and their exterior derivatives and integrals) as equivalence classes.

@Ted: is the point here that with antisymmetric tensors it's easier to describe how to pair differential forms with (tuples of?) tangent vectors? I admit I haven't actually worked through the foundational machinery of differential forms myself but the two definitions are equivalent in characteristic $0$ (and the positive characteristic situation confuses me a lot) so anything that can be done in one can be done in the other.

Oh, I know they’re equivalent, and certainly with exterior algebra with vector bundles, for example, the quotient viewpoint is preferable.

@TedShifrin Do not be afraid of equivalence classes! Of course, when one does introduce everything in an introductory class it looks very formal, but in "concrete" calculations it does not matter. There will always be an obvious choice of representative and you just calculate.

@JannikPitt Are you giving advice on how to handle differential geometry and calculus to a Professor Emeritus who specialized in differential geometry? ;)

@Didier How does that matter? I just replied to the notion of equivalence classes being "awkward".

@JannikPitt, re, I daresay that, as a general statement, "there will always be an obvious choice of representative [of an equivalence class]" is not true (and, even when it is, it might be better to pretend that it isn't). Maybe you meant in this particular case, but, as @‍QiaochuYuan has already mentioned, even here one runs into trouble in positive characteristic.

@JannikPitt Did not mean to sound rude nor pedantic, sorry if it was the case. I was just implying that someone who studied and taught pure math for the past 30 years surely knows all of these, and is presumably not afraid of definitions, but might just have enough experience to know, in that specific context, what is actually preferable/useful to consider (even though there is no universal ubiquitous agreement). Here, the "canonical" representatives are exactly the antisymmetric tensors, so why not use them directly?

See my answer here. In short (and also to expand on it a bit), using you definition of $\mathscr A$ with the $1/k!$ out front lets us define a wedge product such that
$$
  v_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge v_k := \mathscr A(v_1\otimes\dotsb\otimes v_k),\quad X\wedge Y := \mathscr A(X\otimes Y)
$$
where $v_1,\dotsc,v_k\in V$ are vectors and $X,Y$ alternating tensors. This is very natural because $\mathscr A^2 = \mathscr A$ makes it a (vector space) projection; and also because the natural projection $\pi : {\bigotimes}V\to{\bigwedge}V$ derived from the universal property of the tensor algebra ${\bigotimes}V$ satisfies $\pi\circ\mathscr A = \pi$, meaning that in a sense the action of $\pi$ on a tensor "already" involves applying $\mathscr A$.
Now, there are two exterior algebras we're interested in: ${\bigwedge}V$ and ${\bigwedge}V^*$. They also interact: there is a single (up to some signs) canonical way to define a bilinear pairing ${\bigwedge}V^*\times{\bigwedge}V\to\mathbb R$, or (what is the same thing) to define a linear isomorphism ${\bigwedge}V^*\cong({\bigwedge}V)^*$.
If you commit to using $\mathscr A$ to embed ${\bigwedge V}$ in ${\bigotimes}V$, then you are forced by this bilinear pairing to embed ${\bigwedge}V^*$ in ${\bigotimes}V^*$ as follows:
$$
  \omega_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge\omega_k := \mathscr A_0(\omega_1\otimes\dotsb\otimes\omega_k),\quad \Omega\wedge\Phi := \frac1{k!l!}\mathscr A_0(\Omega\otimes\Phi) = \frac{(k+l)!}{k!l!}\mathscr A(\Omega\otimes\Phi)
$$
where $\omega_1,\dotsc,\omega_k\in V^*$, $\Omega$ is an alternating $k$-tensor, $\Phi$ is an alternating $l$-tensor, and
$$
  \mathscr A_0(\omega_1\otimes\dotsb\otimes\omega_k) = \sum_{\sigma\in S_k}\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma)\omega_{\sigma(1)}\otimes\dotsb\otimes\omega_{\sigma(k)}
$$
is the unnormalized antisymmetrization operation.
A way to summarize this is to say that

Elements of ${\bigwedge}V$, thought of as multivectors representing subspaces of $V$, embed into the tensor algebra via $\mathscr A$.
Elements of ${\bigwedge}V^*$ thought of as differential forms acting on mulvivectors/subspaces of $V$ embed into the tensor algebra via $\mathscr A_0$.


Rewritten shorter but more rigorous answer:
You have to distinguish between a vector space $V$ and its dual $V^*$, which is a derived object.
$V^*\otimes V^*$ is easier to define than $V\otimes V$. It is the space of bilinear functions on $V$ and the tensor product of $\theta^1,\theta^2 \in V^*$ is
$$ (\theta^1\otimes\theta^2)(v_1,v_2) = \theta^1(v_1)\theta^2(v_2). $$
Then $\Lambda^2V^*$ is naturally defined as the subspace of $V^*\otimes V^*$ that contains all antisymmetric bilinear functions on $V$.
The tensor product of $V$ with itself can now be defined as $$V\otimes V = (V^*\otimes V^*)^* $$ and the tensor product of $v, w \in V$ by $$(v\otimes w)(f) = f(v,w). $$
Recall that if $S$ is a subspace of a vector space $X$, then $$S^* = X^*/S^\perp.$$ We can therefore define $$ \Lambda^2V = (\Lambda^2V^*)^* = (V^*\otimes V^*)^*/(\Lambda^2V^*)^\perp = (V\otimes V)/S^2V,$$ where $S^2V = (\Lambda^2V^*)^\perp$.
The wedge product on $V$ now has the natural definition
$$ v_1\wedge v_2 = [v_1\otimes v_2] = \frac{1}{2}[v_1\otimes v_2 - v_2\otimes v_1], $$ where $[\cdot]$ denotes the equivalence class.
We then define the wedge product on $V^*$ by requiring that, if $(b_1, \dots, b_n)$ is a basis of $V$ and $(\beta^1, \dots, \beta^n)$ is a basis of $V^*$, then
$$ (\beta^1\wedge\beta^2)(b_1\wedge b_2) = 1. $$
This implies that
$$
\theta^1\wedge\theta^2 = \theta^1\otimes\theta^2-\theta^2\otimes\theta^1.
$$
and$$ (\beta^j\wedge\beta^k)(b_j,b_k) = (\beta^j\wedge\beta^k)(b_j\wedge b_k) = 1, $$
This is the right normalization for the geometric interpretation in terms of areas of parallelograms.
All of this can be extended in a straightforward way to $k$-tensors and the wedge product of an exterior $k$-tensor with an exterior $l$-tensor.
Everything above can be shown to be functorial and satisfy appropriate universal properties.

Your sentence "Then $\Lambda^2 V$ is naturally defined as the subspace of antisymmetric bilinear" does not end. (I'd also plead that, if one is concerned with the algebraic world, then $\frac1 2$ is no more guaranteed to exist than is $\frac1{\sqrt2}$, but perhaps that pushes the algebraicity too far.)

@LSpice, I added the missing text. I think you have a point with the $\frac{1}{2}$.This is supposed to all work for a (free?) nodule over $\mathbb{Z}$, right? I gotta work out the details on that.

@LSpice, apologies! I I hope it's fixed now.

Looks good! My second comment is now irrelevant, so I'll delete it, and this one eventually.

Regarding the $1/2$ issue, more generally in positive characteristics what happens is that we always have a pairing $\Psi:{\bigwedge}V^*\times{\bigwedge}V\to\mathbb K$ but ${\bigwedge}V$ cannot be embedded in the tensor algebra because we can't construct an associative wedge product there. However, we can still embed exterior powers into tensor powers by using the unnormalized alternating tensors. But the pairing we get from this embedding is $k!\Psi$ on alternating $k$-tensors, and this is zero for some $k$ in positive characteristic, so we cannot recover $\Psi$ this way.

I don't think that $\Psi$ can be derived naturally descending from the tensor algebra in this case. This embedding of exterior powers into tensor powers is also not compatible with the projection ${\bigotimes}V\to{\bigwedge}$ coming from the universal property of the tensor algebra ${\bigotimes}V$.

@NicholasTodoroff, where or what is $\Psi$? Here's a short summary of how I now see things: 1) Define $V^\otimes V^$ as space of bilinear functions on $V$ 2) Define $\Lambda^2V^\subset V^\otimes V^$ as subspace of antisymmetric bilinear functions. 3) There is a canonical isomorphism $V^\otimes V^=(V\otimes V)^$. 4) The natural dual of $\Lambda^2V^$ is $$(\Lambda^2V^)^* = (V^\otimes V^)^/(\Lambda^2V^)^\perp=(V\otimes V)/(\Lambda^2V^)^\perp.$$ Define $S^2V= (\Lambda^2V^)^\perp$ and $$\Lambda^2V=(\Lambda^2V^)^ = (V\otimes V)/S^2V.$$

@Deane $\Psi$ can be derived a number of ways. One way that works even with $V$ a module is to use the canonical coalgebra structure on ${\bigwedge}V$ to construct a product on $({\bigwedge}V)^$; then $V^$ naturally embeds in $({\bigwedge}V)^$ by declaring its action on non-vector multivectors to be zero. Then the universal property gives the isomorphism ${\bigwedge}V^\cong({\bigwedge}V)^*$, which is $\Psi$. See Quadratic Mappings and Clifford Algebras by Micali and Helmstetter.

When the characteristic is not two, my favorite way is to construct the Clifford algebra $Cl(V^\oplus V)$ with bilinear form given by $$(V^\oplus V)^* \cong (V^)^\oplus V^* \cong V\oplus V^\cong V^\oplus V.$$ Both ${\bigwedge}V$ and ${\bigwedge}V^$ embed naturally in $Cl(V^\oplus V)$. Now let $\langle X\rangle = tr(X)/tr(1)$ where $tr(X)$ is the trace of $Y\mapsto XY$ in $Cl(V^*\oplus W)$. Now $\Psi$ is the restriction of the form $(X,Y)\mapsto\langle XY\rangle$.

As you've define them, ${\bigwedge^2}V^$ lives in a tensor power but ${\bigwedge^2}V$ lives in a quotient of a tensor power. How do you defining a pairing ${\bigwedge^2}V^\times{\bigwedge^2}V\to\mathbb K$ in this case? In positive characteristic I don't think you can do it from this tensor perspective, which is the point I was trying to make.

@NicholasTodoroff, since I define $\Lambda^2V = (\Lambda^2V^)^$, the pairing is there by definition.

@Deane Ok. I think I was confused because you've written some isomorphisms as equalities. Well, if we declare something to be true, then it is. I suppose I think of these objects as defined by their universal properties, and I'm most interested in the structures that arise from that. When you work with a construction like this, what I can't help thinking is "is this inherent to the 'exterior' structure, or is this 'merely' a result of the particular construction?" But if that doesn't bother you, then I don't think there's anything wrong with this approach, at least for exterior powers.

As for how you define the wedge product $v\wedge w$ of ${\bigwedge^2}V$ defined like this, you have to say something like: it is the element $X \in ({\bigwedge^2}V^)^$ defined by $X(\Phi) = \Phi(v\otimes w)$ for all $\Phi \in {\bigwedge^2}V$.

@NicholasTodoroff, as I say in the last sentence, these can all be defined as functors between the appropriate categories and therefore satisfy the relevant universal properties. So they are not ad hoc. I chose not to define everything in terms of universal properties, because it's longer and harder to follow. Instead, I provided explicit definitions. The universal properties can be verified easily, for example, using bases for all of the vector spaces.

I don't understand your last comment. Maybe there's a typo?  If $v, w \in V$, then $v\wedge w \in (\Lambda^2V^)^$ is defined as follows: For any $\Theta \in \Lambda^2V^*$, $$(v\wedge w)(\Theta) = \Theta(v,w). $$ This is equivalent to the definition I give in my answer.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
